# É possível capturar a url atual na view do blade?

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-blade

Gostaria de capturar a url exemplo, `/user/**` (tudo que iniciar com /user), estou usando laravel e blade, usando Request::url() eu pego `localhost:8000` porém preciso de algo que consiga capturar as rotas. Agradeço

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para conseguir o url na view pode fazer:

```
<p>{{Request::url()}}</p>
```

Para verificar se como segundo segmento do url tem "user":

```
@if(explode('/', Request::url())[3] == 'user')
    // tem '/user'
@endif
```

Mandar isto do controller é capaz de ser melhor ideia:

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
    if($request->segments()[0] == 'user') {
        // url tem como primeiro segmento "user"
    }
}
```

Ainda [outra possível solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591181/how-to-get-the-current-url-inside-if-statement-blade-in-laravel-4), sem ter testado, desculpe se não resultar:

```
if (Request::is('user/*'))
{
     // code
}
```

Comment: Excelente resposta, mas uma sugestão, poderia passar isso via controler não? Assim chegaria mais "limpo" ao view, do meu ponto de vista algumas coisas são preferíveis no controller. É apenas uma sugestão.

Comment: Claro que sim @GuilhermeNascimento, vou acrescentar

Comment: @Miguel thank you, fiz um pouco diferente mas seguindo sua logica, abraço.

Comment: De nada @FelipePaetzold. Ainda bem que ajudei

Answer (score 1):

Eu faço assim no blade:

```
//http://localhost:8000/user/teste

//Pegar o primeiro que é "user"
Request::segment(1)

//Pegar o segundo é "teste"
Request::segment(2)
```

Ele já ignora a URL padrão e pega direto a rota.

No caso para verificar se começa com "user" vc faria assim no blade:

```
{{ Request::segment(1) == 'user' ? 'verdadeiro' : 'falso' }}
```

Ou:

```
@if(Request::segment(1) == 'user')
    //Suas instruções aqui
@endif
```